# How can I stop completely IntelliJ of intrusively auto formatting whilst I type?

Tags: intellij-idea, formatting

How can I disable the oppinionated and intrusive auto formatting provided by IntelliJ completely, globally, permanently? If I need to format anything, I will explicitly ask for that.

Any help is infinitely well appreciated.

Comment: @payloc : Everything. I don't need any sort of formatting at all. I just need IntelliJ to do what I ask **when** I ask. If I do not ask, please don't do anything without my consent. There are times when IntelliJ stubbornly formats my code without my consent. Then I need to resort to Emacs to get the job done! This is crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys: turn off "Reformat block on typing }" and "Smart indent". There are other options on this page which you may also want to turn off, even though they don't control specifically formatting.

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my week. I was really pissed off with IntelliJ this morning.